# Deleting Individual SE Accounts

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

Is there any way to remove individual SE accounts for particular SE sites?  So in other words, say I want to keep my current Stack Overflow account just like it is.  But say I want to delete my account on Server Fault so that it no longer exists and doesn't show up in my SE/SO profile.

Is there any way to do that?

Recap: Keep current login (and certain Stack Exchange sites) but remove particular SE sites' membership for my particular login.  Does that make sense?

**Current Accounts**
Me - StackOverflow
Me - SuperUser
Me - ServerFault

**Desired End Result Accounts**
Me - StackOverflow
Me - SuperUser

Where the *desired end result accounts* will be the same user (Me) with the persistent questions/answers/reputation/etc.

Comment: Do you want your Server Fault account to disappear altogether such that any posts you had there will no longer have your name? (If you made substantial contributions there, I don't think the team is willing to delete them along with your SF account.)

Comment: @BoltClock The ideal would be to have them deleted (or orphaned), but the second best option would be to just get that profile away from my particular login.  Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If your account has never voted or posted a question or answer you should see a self-delete option on your user page.

However, if your account *has* voted or posted, do the following:

1. **Edit the "about me" field in your profile to say "please delete me"** so SE can confirm your ownership of the account.
2. **Obtain your user page URL or numeric user ID**. This is linked from the top of every page of the site when you are logged in.
3. **Email the support address linked at the bottom of every web page** on the site. Where it says "contact us", click that. In your email, you **MUST** include your user page URL or user ID so SE can find your account.

Also of note, SE automatically cull old inactive accounts as documented here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Source-[Click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)